# Merge three NumPy arrays of same shapes

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a `numpy` array `l1` of shape `(128, 128, 3)` and data type `np.bool`. All elements of `l1` are `False`. I have also three arrays `first_l2`, `second_l2` and `third_l2` of shape `(128, 128, 1)` and data type `np.bool`.

What I want to know is how to merge `first_l2`, `second_l2` and `third_l2` into `l1` such that corresponding elements of former arrays are in the correct order inside `l1`.

Comment: Just use array slicing, `l1[:, :, 0] = first_l2`, `l1[:, :, 1] = second_l2`, and so on...

Comment: @Holt But there is a problem, which is `l1[:, :, 0]` will return an array of shape `(128,128)` but l2 is in shape of `(128,128,1)`  ?????

Comment: Squeeze L2 before assigning or use another slicing for L2.

Comment: Thanks, `l1[:, :, 0] = l2[:, :, 0]` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to join the three arrays through [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) rather than the hardcoding approach proposed by @Holt.

Let us assume that you have three arrays of shape `(128, 128, 1)` and you want to combine them into a single array of shape `(128, 128, 3)`.

```
In [313]: import numpy as np

In [314]: arr1 = np.random.random(size=(128, 128, 1))

In [315]: arr2 = np.random.random(size=(128, 128, 1))

In [316]: arr3 = np.random.random(size=(128, 128, 1)
```

To accomplish that you just need to pass the arrays to the `concatenate` function like this:

```
In [317]: out1 = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2, arr3), axis=-1)
```

The hardcoding approach would yield the same result, but it is more verbose and the resulting array has to be explicitly allocated:

```
In [318]: out2 = np.empty(shape=(128, 128, 3))

In [319]: out2[:, :, 0] = arr1[:, :, 0]

In [320]: out2[:, :, 1] = arr2[:, :, 0]

In [321]: out2[:, :, 2] = arr3[:, :, 0]

In [322]: print(np.all(out1 == out2))
True
```

It should be noticed that the method proposed in @Lauro Bravar's answer does not provide the expected result since `stack` joins the arrays along a new axis.

```
In [323]: out3 = np.stack((arr1, arr2, arr3))

In [324]: print(out3.shape)
(3, 128, 128, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a function in *numpy* called [**stack**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). If I understood your question correctly it should do exactly what you are asking for :)

For example:

```
array1 = np.array([[True, True],[False, False]])
array2 = np.array([[False, False],[True, True]])
array3 = np.array([[False, True],[True, False]])
```

Now you stack them:

```
stacked = np.stack((array1, array2, array3))

stacked
> array([[[True, True],[False, False]],
         [[False, False],[True, True]],
         [[False, True],[True, False]]])

stacked.shape
> (3, 2, 2)
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
l1[:, :, 0] = first_l2[:, :, 0]
l1[:, :, 1] = second_l2[:, :, 0]
l1[:, :, 2] = third_l2[:, :, 0]
```

credit goes to @Holt